# How To Download All FreeBSD distfiles

Tags: freebsd, repository, bsd-ports

How can I download **all** FreeBSD distfiles into /usr/ports/distfiles so that I have them for offline use? I realize it will be a huge download.

I remember reading how to do this (possibly in the [Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/)) but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just my luck, right after I posted this question I found an answer.

```
make fetch-recursive
```

Here's the applicable info from the [Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/):

> For users who cannot be connected to the Internet all the time, make
>   fetch can be run within /usr/ports, to fetch all distfiles, or within
>   a category, such as /usr/ports/net, or within the specific port
>   skeleton. Note that if a port has any dependencies, running this
>   command in a category or ports skeleton will not fetch the distfiles
>   of ports from another category. Instead, use make fetch-recursive to
>   also fetch the distfiles for all the dependencies of a port.

---

This was very hard to find using Google so hopefully this question and answer will help posterity. Sorry for turning this into a blog post of sorts.